# Abstract Monomorphism 3 part Question

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

I have been working on this problem for an hour now and gotten nowhere:

Let $G$ be any group and $A(G)$ the set of all 1-1 mappings of $G$, as a set, onto itself. Define $L_a : G \rightarrow  G$ by $L_a(x) = xa^{-1}$. Prove that:

(a) $L_a$ is an element of $A(G)$

(b) $L_aL_b = L_{ab}$

(c) The mapping $\psi : G \rightarrow A(G)$ defined by $\psi(a) = L_a$ is a monomorphism of $G$ into $A(G)$

Comment: What have you worked out so far?

Comment: Nowhere? Did you manage (a)? If not, what is the difficulty with (a)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints which almost solve everything:

(a) You need to find a left inverse... maybe consider $L_{a^{-1}}$.

(b) Write it out and you will see that $b^{-1}a^{-1} = (ab)^{-1}$ will do the job.

(c) So if $L_a = L_b$ you need to figure out, that $a=b$ for injectivity. How can you do so? just write down what the maps do on an element $x \in G$. And use (b) for the proof that this map is a homomorphism.

Comment: Thank you very much, your hints were more than enough!

Comment: Sorry I am very new here, it will not allow upvotes until I have 15 rep  points.

Comment: I am glad that I could help. Have fun on MSE then.